# Converting dataframe columns from lists

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I have what I consist a tricky situation. I used a nested lapply statement and I am trying to extract the results into a dataframe. The method I used to extract the result is below. The first element in the list is the year of the data, with 1 being 2014, 2 2015 etc. I used other approach which produced the same outcome

```
runs_results_1 <- as.data.frame(Reduce(rbind, runs_year[[1]]))
```

The real problem is that when I run the following code

```
sapply(runs_results_1, mode)
```

It returns the following for the dataframe. With the columns being lists it is annoying to use the data.

```
statistic     p.value        runs          mu         var      method   
data.name 
 "list"      "list"      "list"      "list"      "list"      "list"      
 "list" 
alternative     players 
 "list"      "list"
```

Is there a way to convert each of the columns from a list into a numeric or character column? I realize i am not providing a workable example and from other possibles it seems this is a technical answer as to how R structure things. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the best approach  `cc <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(runs_results_1), nrow = 681, byrow = T))` once I know the number of columns?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Maybe show how you created this object in the first place; there may be a better way.

Comment: Sorry @MrFlick but it would have been very messy to do over this forum. I have a workable solution now but it probably is not the most efficient way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column lists are single element atomic lists, then you can use the "unlist" command, e.g.:

```
df <- sapply(df, unlist)
```

Comment: Thanks. This did work and does not rely on knowing the number of rows in advance. It just needs a small adjust due to the collection not being an atomic vector